# Java: avoid Concurrent Modification Exception with ListIterator while modifying a List in a loop

Tags: java, list, addition, listiterator

Using Java, I have a list to be checked and in case one of the sublists retrieved through a loop meets some condition, it must be replaced on the fly, since in the next loop I must repeat the algorithm on the changed list. The sublist to be replaced and that to add can have different lengths of course.

I am using a ListIterator since adding and removing using normal List methods can't guarantee the result. But even here, a ConcurrentModificationException is thrown at the beginning of the first for loop (at its second iteration) inside the main for loop, and I can't really think of another way to perform the algorithm.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.ListIterator;

public class Dummy {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<String> nodes = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(
                "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7"));
        ListIterator<String> nodesIterator = nodes.listIterator();
        while (nodesIterator.hasNext()) {
            nodesIterator.next();
            List<String> nodesToCheck = nodes.subList(nodesIterator
                            .previousIndex(),
                    nodesIterator.previousIndex() + 3);
            if (nodesToCheck.equals(Arrays.asList("3", "4", "5"))) {
                List<String> nodesToReplace = new ArrayList<String>(
                        Arrays.asList("11", "11", "00", "11"));
                for (String n : nodesToCheck) {
                    //ConcurrentModificationException thrown here at 
                    // beginning of second iteration
                    nodesIterator.remove();
                    nodesIterator.next();
                }
                for (String n : nodesToReplace) {
                    nodesIterator.add(n);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Any help is extremely appreciated, thanks ;)

Comment: Rewrite the code so that it compiles (use `List<String>` also)  if you want any further help

Comment: @Mr_and_Mrs_D check the updated question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're modifying the initial nodes list so it's natural that an exception is thrown. You should iterate over a copy of the nodes list.

Here is a runnable example that reproduces the problem (I wrote before OP was edited):

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.ListIterator;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int number = 2;
        List<String> nodes = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList("Hello",
            "World!", "How", "Are", "You"));
        ListIterator<String> nodesIterator = nodes.listIterator();
        while (nodesIterator.hasNext()) {
            nodesIterator.next();
            int fromIndex = nodesIterator.previousIndex();
            List<String> nodesToCheck = nodes.subList(fromIndex,fromIndex + number);
            if (nodesToCheck.contains("Hello")) {
                for (String n : nodesToCheck) { //ConcurrentModificationException 
                    // thrown here at beginning of second iteration
                    nodesIterator.remove();
                    nodesIterator.next();
                }
                List<String> nodesToReplace = new ArrayList<>(
                    Arrays.asList("replace"));
                for (String n : nodesToReplace) {
                    nodesIterator.add(n);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

A quick and dirty way of patching this (which can be necessary in more complex designs) is:

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int number = 2;
        List<String> nodes = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList("Hello", "World!",
                "How", "Are", "You"));
        boolean change = true;
        while (change) {
            List<String> copy = new ArrayList<>(nodes);
            ListIterator<String> nodesIterator = copy.listIterator();
            while (nodesIterator.hasNext()) {
                nodesIterator.next();
                int fromIndex = nodesIterator.previousIndex();
                List<String> nodesToCheck = nodes.subList(fromIndex, Math.min
                        (fromIndex + number, nodes.size()));
                if ((nodesToCheck.equals(Arrays.asList("How", "Are")) ||
                        nodesToCheck.equals(Arrays.asList("Hello", "World!")))) {
                    for (String n : nodesToCheck) {
                        //ConcurrentModificationException thrown here
                        // at beginning of second iteration
                        nodesIterator.remove();
                        if (nodesIterator.hasNext()) {
                            nodesIterator.next();
                        }
                    }
                    nodesIterator.previous();
                    List<String> nodesToReplace = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList
                            ("replace"));
                    for (String n : nodesToReplace) {
                        nodesIterator.add(n);
                    }
                    nodes = copy;
                    change = true;
                    break;
                } else change = false;
            }
        }
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(nodes.toArray()));
    }
}
```

Although it can be further simplified. That's a general programming approach to such problems however - while there is something changing rerun through the collection and modify till there is no change.

Comment: Ok, but how do I replace the original list in the next while iteration? The list can be different

Comment: @Simon Edit your question so the code runs - create a nodes list and write the condition `some_condition_on_nodesToCheck`

Comment: @Simon: Make something simpler that reproduces the problem

Comment: Back :) this solution currently works just for one verification of the condition. Say, if the condition were for example `if (nodesToCheck.equals(Arrays.asList("How", "Are")) ||            nodesToCheck.equals(Arrays.asList("Hello", "World!")))`, this would just verify for the second operand but not for the first. By the way, you probably forgot to add a `nodesIterator.previous();` before the add loop, I'll edit the answer :)

Comment: Actually, while debugging, I noticed that `break outer;` behaves just like a normal `break;`, i.e. it doesn't reach the label and exits the `while (nodesIterator.hasNext())` loop

Comment: @Simon: the conditions failing was due to lack of `nodesIterator.previous();` - I had not called previous() cause you didn't in your question (neither original nor edited). I don't know what exactly you want to do nor am I supposed to write your code for you - these details you have to work out yourself - use answers here for specific problems (here the problem is basically how to modify a list while iterating over it and it's a general problem that has one general solution among others which is the one presented here).

Comment: The `break` behavior however tripped me too. Edited the answer to address all concerns :)

Comment: Thanks @Mr_and_Mrs_D, it seems to work now, I'm studying different variations of this case. Another solution can be to use `CopyOnWriteArrayList` instead of declaring `nodes` as `ArrayList` and using the change loop with `copy`. One must also take care of the conditions, especially if you have two sets of lists to be checked and to replace.

Comment: Thanks - no prob - [CopyOnWriteArrayList](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CopyOnWriteArrayList.html) would be very inefficient if there are alot of mutations plus the iterator does not ever see modifications so beware